# What's the difference between "cut out of" and "cut out from"?

Tags: meaning, differences, word-usage, phrase-usage

For example: This piece was cut out of/from the red fabric.

I see on the internet that people use both versions, but can't quite get the difference... or maybe I can use them interchangeably?

Comment: to explain the phrase "cut out of" they use "from" so I'm confused...

"cut out of
to cut a pattern or shape from cloth, paper, sheet metal, etc.; to remove something from something by cutting; to excise something from something. (When both out and of are used, no direct object can intervene.) Sam cut a pig out from the paper. I cut the picture out of a magazine. I cut out the shape of the moon from the paper"